# Why does EasyNewsletter for plone throw NameError on 'toLocalizedTime

Tags: plone

I have installed EasyNewsletter, but whenever I add an issue, I get a traceback claiming:

NameError: name 'toLocalizedTime' is not defined

How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback; just the last line is not helpful I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is filed and fixed:
https://github.com/collective/Products.EasyNewsletter/commit/9d756f22c3117aa239c60283a8249edb56b9bf8f

Contact the authors to ask for a new release or apply the fix yourself, according to the link above.

The reason lies in the 'no more global definitions'-changement from Plone-3 to Plone-4, see further explanations on:
http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-3-x-to-4.0/updating-add-on-products-for-plone-4.0/no-more-global-definitions-in-templates